# How to write this SQL code in Drupal 7 standards!

Tags: 7, database

So basically i am developing a module which is using Another Database,NOT THE DEFAULT DB and it is connecting successfully.
I have this SQL query which runs Smoothly in my custom MVC application.
Now Running the same code in Drupal Gives me error!

Below is the Code

```
function market_summary(){

$sql = 'select s1.company,(s1.closingprice-s2.closingprice)/100 as diff from stocks as s1
  INNER JOIN stocks as s2 ON s1.company = s2.company 
     s1.dpid = (select max(dpid) from stocks) and s2.dpid = (select max(dpid)-1 from stocks)';

$mymodule= Database::getConnection($target='default',$key='$mymodule');
$result = $mymodule->query($sql);
$output='';

foreach($result as $record){


 $output.=$record->company.'<br/>';

 }
      return $output;
}
```

I want to know how to write the SQL part of this Code in Drupal standards.
I have attached a screenshot, showing the error message.
I will Appriciate for any help.
[image: Erro message from SQL]

Comment: I can probably write a full answer but just to check, it looks like you're missing the WHERE clause before `s1.dpid`. It's also advisable to enclose tables names in curly brackets.

Comment: How did i miss the "WHERE" clause?i dont know.. Thank you @leexonline you are the Magician.